Prevent login of the same user multiple times with Vaadin 24 and Spring Security 6
I have a Vaadin 24 + Springboot 3 using spring security 6.3. I have a custom login page. Everything works fine except for sessions. Session concurrency cannot be managed whatever i tried.
My Security Config:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {
    
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }
    @Bean
    public Filter disableOptionsMethodFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                String method = request.getMethod();
                if ("OPTIONS".equals(method) || "DELETE".equals(method) || "PATCH".equals(method)
                        || "PUT".equals(method)) {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
                }
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.addFilterBefore(disableOptionsMethodFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        
        .headers(headers -> headers
                .xssProtection(xss -> xss.headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.ENABLED_MODE_BLOCK))
                .frameOptions(frame -> frame.sameOrigin())
                .referrerPolicy(referrer -> referrer.policy(ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN)))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .invalidSessionUrl("/").maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/").maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()));
        
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
        super.configure(http);
    }

    
    
}

My Login Logic:

private void doLogin(String username, String password) {
        if (captcha.checkUserAnswer(captchatext.getValue())) {
            
            try {
                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
                Authentication authenticated = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticated);

                if (authenticated.isAuthenticated()) {
                    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
                    securityRepo.saveContext(context, VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent(), VaadinServletResponse.getCurrent());
                    UI.getCurrent().navigate(HomeView.class);
                } else {
                    Notification.show("Error");
                   
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Notification.show("Authentication failed");
                
            }
        } else {
            Notification.show("Invalid captcha");
            
        }
    }

If I use login component of Vaadin with login.setAction("login"), everything works fine.

I can confirm that it does not work like that out of the box. There seems to be some issue in Spring Security preventing that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3078
As I workaround what seems to work is to register the event publisher (otherwise the session registry is not getting updated correctly) and register right version of the authentication strategy:
@Bean
public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(disableOptionsMethodFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .headers(headers -> headers
                    .xssProtection(
                            xss -> xss.headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.ENABLED_MODE_BLOCK))
                    .frameOptions(frame -> frame.sameOrigin())
                    .referrerPolicy(referrer -> referrer.policy(ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN)))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/")
                    .sessionConcurrency(cust -> cust
                            .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/")
                            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true))
                    .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy())
                    .sessionFixation().changeSessionId());

    super.configure(http);

    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
}

Note, logout needs to be implemented properly.
Button logout = new Button("Logout", click -> securityService.logout());

And implement utility function
public void logout() {
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    logoutHandler.logout(
            VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getHttpServletRequest(), null,
            null);
}

Alternatively instead you could use the other mode of configuration by setting maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false), when new login of the user is accepted and the previous one is invalidated automatically:
    http.addFilterBefore(disableOptionsMethodFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .headers(headers -> headers
            .xssProtection(xss -> xss.headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.ENABLED_MODE_BLOCK))
            .frameOptions(frame -> frame.sameOrigin())
            .referrerPolicy(referrer -> referrer.policy(ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN)))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/")
                    .sessionConcurrency(cust -> cust
                        .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/")
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)));


Thank you so much for the reply. But it does not solve the problem. I can still login with the same user multiple times.

I found a workaround.

Thanks again Tatu. But unfortunately, the issue persists . The Bean: httpSessionEventPublisher is not used anywhere. Could it be some issue with  :
securityRepo.saveContext(context, VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent(), VaadinServletResponse.getCurrent());

IIDE is not giving me that warning. And the solution worked for me at least. I.e. with that code the user can login after logout. Without the workarounds the re-login does not work.

Thank you for the help Mr. Tatu.  But nothing seems to work. At the end, i ended up manually invalidating the sessions. I will post the solution which may be helpful to others later.

I added the logout function I use to my code snippets. As stated earlier, that works.

Working solution: So, I ended up having to register the session manually after checking if the user has any previous and invalidating those sessions.
private void doLogin(String username, String password) {
        invalidatePreviousSessionsForUser(username);
        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
            Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
            SecurityContext context = this.securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
            context.setAuthentication(authentication);
            this.securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);
            securityRepo.saveContext(context, VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent(), VaadinServletResponse.getCurrent());
            registerSession(VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession(),
                    (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal());
            UI.getCurrent().navigate(HomeView.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Notification.show("Authentication failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

Register Session
@Autowired
SessionRegistry sr;
    private void registerSession(WrappedSession session, UserDetails userDetails) {
            sr.registerNewSession(session.getId(), userDetails);
        }

invalidate sessions:
public int getActiveSessionCountForUser(String username) {
        int count = 0;
        List<Object> principals = sr.getAllPrincipals();
        for (Object principal : principals) {
            if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
                UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
                if (userDetails.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                    List<SessionInformation> sessionInfoList = sr.getAllSessions(userDetails, true); // Invalidate
                                                                                                        // previous
                                                                                                        // sessions
                    count += sessionInfoList.size();
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void invalidatePreviousSessionsForUser(String username) {
        // Get active session count for the user
        int activeSessionCount = getActiveSessionCountForUser(username);

        // If there are active sessions for the user, invalidate them
        if (activeSessionCount > 0) {
            List<Object> principals = sr.getAllPrincipals();
            for (Object principal : principals) {
                if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
                    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
                    if (userDetails.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                        List<SessionInformation> sessionInfoList = sr.getAllSessions(userDetails, true); // Invalidate
                                                                                                            // previous
                                                                                                            // sessions
                        for (SessionInformation sessionInfo : sessionInfoList) {
                            sessionInfo.expireNow(); // Expire session information

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

